# how to remove nan in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, nan

i have input numeric field with format like 20,000.00

how to remove Nan if user not key in the first field?

```js
document.getElementById("BasicSalary_x").onblur =function (){    
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ""))
                    .toFixed(2)
                    .toString()
                    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    
     
    
}

 function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = ((evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode);
    return !(charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 && charCode != 44 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel"  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="BasicSalary_x" placeholder="Basic Salary (RM)"   >


<input type="tel" value="0.00" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="deduction" placeholder="Deduction (RM)"   >
```

Comment: sorry just removed display_BasicSalary_x , if dont fill the first field and use tab to next field will appear Nan

Comment: check if the field is empty before processing it: `if (document.getElementById('BasicSalary_x').value != '') { ... }`

Comment: @GrafiCode will still give `NaN` if you paste in non-numeric

Comment: @freedomn-m I didn't know one could paste non-numeric values in `input type="tel"` , thanks for the clarification

Comment: @GrafiCode not something I've used much - just trying OPs code.  OPs code is blocking the non-numeric input (but not paste), not `type=tel` which, it turns out, doesn't block anything.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

Answer (score 3):

If you get `NaN` with `parseFloat`, then you can use `||0` to convert it to zero (or any default you prefer).

```
parseFloat("x,xx".replace(/,/g, "")) || 0
```

Alternatively, you can check if it's a number with `isNaN`

```
var val = this.value.replace(/,/g, "");
if (isNaN(val)) {
    alert("Please only enter valid values.");
} else {
    ... parseFloat(val) ...
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN